# Sum of Sequentially Spaced Binomial Terms

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Understanding that if $k>n$, we have that $\binom{n}{k}=0$, has there been any success coming up with closed formulas or asymptotic formulas for the following...

$$B(n,k,j)=\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{ki+j}$$

Certainly many of these partial sums have generating formulas, for example

$$\frac{(1-x)^2}{(1-2x)(1-x+x^2)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B(n,3,0)x^n$$

$$\frac{x^3(x-1)}{(2x-1)(x^4-2x^3+4x^2-32x+1)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B(n,5,2)x^n$$

EDIT:  I am aware of such theorems as the [series multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection) and am trying to see if there exists closed forms outside of summation operations or products...

Comment: One can get closed forms using $k$-th roots of unity.

Comment: I've seen and derived some other summations using $k$th roots of unity, but i have never seen a closed form with them...

Comment: Like for $k=3, j=1$, $$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}(1+w_3^{2i+1}+w_3^{i+2})$$

Comment: @AndréNicolas, I've also seen information regarding [series multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection)

Comment: For example, wiith $j=0$ we get I think $\frac{1}{3}\left((1+1)^n+(1+\omega)^n +(1+\omega^2)^n\right)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One dirty trick is *decimation*. Consider a primitive $n$-th root of $1$, e.g.

$\begin{align}
\omega = \exp\left( \frac{2 \pi \mathrm{i}}{n} \right)
\end{align}$

It is easy to prove that:

$\begin{align}
 \sum_{0 \le k < n} \omega^{k s}
   = \begin{cases}
        n & \text{if } n \mid s \\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}
\end{align}$

Consider now a series $A(z) = \sum_{r \ge 0} a_r z^r$. Compute:

$\begin{align}
  \sum_{0 \le k < n} \omega^{-k t} A(\omega^k z)
    &= \sum_{r \ge 0} a_r z^r \sum_{0 \le k < n} \omega^{(r - t) k} \\
    &= n \sum_{k \ge 0} a_{n k + t} z^{n k + t}
\end{align}$

From this you get the formula requested.

Comment: I will amend my question.  I am aware of these, as I mentioned in my comments about series multisection, which is what this answer represents.  I'm looking for even simpler closed forms, but I don't think any exist; closed or explicit forms outside summation or product operators...

Comment: That *is* the "closed form", there can't be another series that is the same.

Comment: I understand and agree, but I'm looking for "simpler", for example, the sum of all binomial coefficients is $2^n$.  One term/expresion.... I know that there are expressions, like yours, that capture the sequence, or calculate efficiently.  I was hoping to see if there was something "more"...

Comment: The (interesting) process you use, @vonbrand is not that "dirty" : it's a Discrete Fourier Transform.